# findstr gets wrong line on commad

Tags: batch-file

i have a list with number of station and ip like this:

```
1   10.1.1.10
10  10.1.10.10
11  10.1.11.10
17  10.1.17.10
174 10.1.174.10
7602    10.16.2
7604    10.16.4
7605    10.16.5
```

the list is very big but this is the example.

i would like to use "findstr" to end number of station with "SET /P"
and get by that the IP.
this is what i've wrote:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p sn=
echo result is :
echo.
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('findstr /c:%sn% stations.list') do set station=%%a %%b %%c
echo %station%
echo.
pause
```

when i try to do some script it gets me for "1" it brings something else with the number "1" but no "1" exactly

Comment: WHen you type in `1` what do you expect to get back?

Comment: forget to mention 10.1.1.10

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/b /e` switches and `1` should get you the IP address on that line.

Your example doesn't use three tokens so I change it to 1,2 also:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p sn=
echo result is :
echo.
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('findstr /b /e /c:%sn% stations.list') do set station=%%a&set IP=%%b
echo %station%, %IP%
echo.
pause
```

Comment: remove the /e and includde a a space at end of search string - findstr /b /c:"%sn% " stations.list. Type findstr /? for help.

Comment: still getting ECHO if off. witout space after strings i'm getting "199 10.1.199.10"

Comment: figure it out! adding TAB instead space, the list is with TAB separate and not space.